# Can I bundle my js via requirejs optimizer and serve the resultant single optimized file from a CDN?

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs

I'm trying to ease the load on my app server.  I'd like it to serve just a small page shell and have my optimized, bundled js served from my CDN.  Can I do this?

I ask because I'm not having any luck doing it, and the first question one should ask in that case is "should I be doing this?"  Maybe it's not the intended workflow for the tool.

The project consists of maybe 100 or so js files (most mine, some 3rd party).  I use AMD via require to make it manageable.  I've run the optimizer and produced a single optimized file.  But when I place that file on my CDN and reference it from a script tag in my project, the app complains as follows:

> ```
>     GET https://myserver.com/modules/util/utilloader.js net::ERR_ABORTED
>     12:50:16.452 require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Script error for "modules/util/utilloader"
>     http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>         at makeError (require.js:168)
>         at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1735)
> ```

It seems like it may be complaining because it wants the components/files to be at paths relative to my app on my server.  But I want it to look for that code within the bundled file.

Is what I'm trying to do feasible?  If so, how do I get the app to look for the code in the optimized file and not in other files relative to the app root on my server?

ADDITIONAL DETAIL (per request):
The config file (application.js) essentially first requires a bunch of 3rd party stuff.  It then requires the modules I made.  That seems to be where the trouble starts.  If you look at the application.js file down below there are two require statements that have paths in the dependency list (utilloader, mod1, mod2, mod3, etc.).  It's never going to find those because they don't exist.  I've bundled those files into one file called application.js.  That's all there is now, just one file.  This dilemma tells me I just don't understand something about this tool and process in general.  How do I require something like utilloader without a path like "modules/util/utilloader"? I would have thought the optimizer would  understand this problem and account for it when it bundles.  But again, I think I don't understand the tool or the process.

Here are the relevant files:

BUILD FILE

```
    ({
        appDir: ".",
        baseUrl: "myapp",
        dir: "../scripts-build",
        mainConfigFile: 'myapp/application.js',
        modules: [
            {
                name: "application"
            }
        ]
    })
```

CODE STRUCTURE (optimizer directory)

> ```
>     -optimize
>         -r
>         -scripts
>             -backbone.js
>             -backbone.marionette.js
>             ...many more 3rd party libs
>             -underscore.js
>             -myapp
>                 -application.js
>                 -controller.js
>                 -router.js
>                 -modules (complex modules each with many dependencies.  Sub-structures omitted here for brevity)
>                     -mod1
>                     -mod2
>                     -mod3
>                     -util
> ```

CONFIG (application.js)

```
    require.config({
        paths: {

            jquery: '../jquery-2.2.3.min',
            bootstrap: '../bootstrap.min',
            jqueryui: '../jquery-ui-1.11.4.min',
            jqcloud: '../jqcloud.min',
            jqmarquee: '../jquery.marquee.min',
            bootstrapslider: '../bootstrap-slider.min',
            underscore: '../underscore.min',
            backbone: '../backbone.min',
            marionette: '../backbone.marionette.min',
            handlebars: '../handlebars.min',
            hls: '../hls.min'

        },

        shim: {   

            'jqueryui': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },

            "bootstrap": {
                "deps": ['jquery']
            },

            'jqcloud': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },

            'jqmarquee': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },

            'bootstrapslider': {
                deps: ['jquery', 'bootstrap']
            },

            underscore: {
                exports: '_'
            },

            backbone: {
                deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
                exports: "Backbone"
            },

            marionette: {
                deps: ["backbone"],
                exports: "Marionette"
            }

        }
    });


    //Outer require - Need this 3rd party stuff to make our Marionette app.  
    //There will be 2 more requires inside this outer require.
    require(["marionette", "hls", "jqueryui", "jqcloud", "jqmarquee", "handlebars", "bootstrap", "bootstrapslider"], function (Marionette, Hls) {


        //Create a Marionette js application
        window.App = new Marionette.Application();


        //Do a bunch of stuff in the app's global space that uses some of the 3rd party packages required above
        ...code ommitted here for brevity


        //#1
        //Require some other modules (mine, not 3rd party) before officially "starting" the marionette js application.
        //Each of these modules include many dependencies (many dozens of files) of thier own in their definitions
        require([
            "modules/util/utilloader",
            "modules/mod1/mod1loader",
            "modules/mod2/mod2loader",
            "modules/mod3/mod3loader"
            ], function () {
            App.start();
        });


        //#2
        //Require two more files (mine) to make a backbone router.
        require(["controller", "router"], function (Controller, AppRouter) {
            var router = new AppRouter({ controller: new Controller() });
        });


        //When the marionette js application is officially "started", start the backbone history.  
        App.on("start", function () { 

            //History
            if (Backbone.history) {
                Backbone.history.start();
            }//End history


            //Some more app start functions
            ...code ommitted here for brevity

        });//end App on start handler




    })//end outer require
```

A SAMPLE MODULE (utilloader.js) REQUIRED BY MY MAIN CONFIG FILE (application.js)

```
    // loader for Util module (lets you spread this module across multiple files)
    // the 'loader' includes initial module definition and manages the loading
    // of all module files including javascript and templates.


    // define base module elements; other module files may depend
    // on this, but it must not depend on any other module files.
    //NOTE:  I think this first piece here is what the optimizer is complaining about
    //It's not inside a define?
    App.module("UtilModule", function (UtilModule) {
        UtilModule.views = {}; //put your views and models in structures so you 
        UtilModule.models = {};//can get at them from anywhere in the module
    });


    // Recommended: define all dependencies for this module
    // while you could spread dependency requirements
    // over all your module files on purely "as needed" basis,
    // this adds to complication of code in your module files
    // defining them all, here, has the advantage of limiting use of RequireJS
    // to this loader file only

    var dependencies = [
        "modules/util/views/view1",
        "modules/util/views/view2",
        "modules/util/views/view3",
        "modules/util/models/model1",
        "modules/util/models/model2",
        "modules/util/models/model3"
    ];


    // define the loader last. generally, it should depend on all
    // module files, otherwise they may not get loaded
    define(dependencies,
        function () {
            App.module("UtilModule", function (UtilModule, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {


            //Some functions here to make views, bind them to the models listed above and show them.
            //...ommitted here for space and clarity


            });//Close the module definition
        });//Close the define function
```

UPDATE 12/13/2017

Maybe my optimized stuff doesn't work because not all of my files are AMD compliant (things not wrapped in define functions).  So I went through the whole project and fixed that.  A sample of the type of revision I did throughout the project is below and the new issue is outlined.

A REVISED SAMPLE MODULE (utilloader.js) REQUIRED BY MY MAIN CONFIG FILE (application.js) THE VERSION OF THIS ABOVE WASN'T LIKED BY THE OPTIMIZER (not AMD compliant).  IT HAD SOME STUFF OUTSIDE THE DEFINE FUNCTION (module definition, var dependencies).  HERE I'VE REVISED IT TO PULL THAT STUFF INSIDE THE DEFINE.  SHOULD HAVE BEEN GOOD NOW.  BUT ON DOING THIS I GET NEW ERRORS. THERE ARE NOW COMPLAINTS THAT THE THINGS DEFINED IN THE EXTERNAL FILES ARE NOT SCOPED IN THIS MODULE.  SO IF, SAY, I DEFINE A BACKBONE MODEL INSIDE AN EXTERNAL FILE LIKE, modules/util/models/model1, ATTEMPTS TO CREATE AN INSTANCE OF THAT MODEL HERE IN THIS FILE GENERATE UNDEFINED ERRORS.  THIS MODULE JUST DOESN'T KNOW WHAT'S IN THOSE EXTERNAL FILES EVEN THOUGH THEY ARE LISTED IN THE DEPENDENCY ARRAY FOR THIS MODULE.  SO REQUIRE IS LOADING THE EXTERNAL FILES WITH NO ERRORS, BUT THE STUFF CREATED IN THEM IS NOT SCOPED HERE IN THIS MODULE.  BUT ALL OF THIS RUNS FINE UNOPTOMIZED (IF I DON'T USE THE OPTIMIZER).  WHY THE DIFFERENCE?  I'D EXPECT IT TO FAIL BOTH WAYS, OR SUCCEED BOTH WAYS IF THE CODE IS MALFORMED IN SOME WAY.

```
    // loader for Util module (lets you spread this module across multiple files)
    // the 'loader' includes initial module definition and manages the loading
    // of all module files including javascript and templates.

    // Recommended: define all dependencies for this module.
    // while you could spread dependency requirements
    // over all your module files on purely "as needed" basis,
    // this adds to complication of code in your module files.
    // defining them all, here, has the advantage of limiting use of RequireJS
    // to this loader file only



    // define the loader last. generally, it should depend on all
    // module files, otherwise they may not get loaded
    define(
        [
            "modules/util/views/view1",
            "modules/util/views/view2",
            "modules/util/views/view3",
            "modules/util/models/model1",
            "modules/util/models/model2",
            "modules/util/models/model3"            
        ],
        function () {
            App.module("UtilModule", function (UtilModule, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

            UtilModule.views = {}; //put your views and models in structures so you 
            UtilModule.models = {};//can get at them from anywhere in the module

            //Try to create an instance of a model defined in an external file. 
            var model1 = new Model1();

            //No errors are reported in the parsing of the external file.  But the line above
            //produces 'Model1' is undefined.  I have dozens of external definitions like this
            //in the app.  All of them resolve fine unoptimized.  When I run the requirejs optimizer,
            //none of them resolve.


            });//Close the module definition
        });//Close the define function
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible, and yes, you should (usually*) be doing this.

If you didn't start out with doing this, you may need to tweak how you do things in your code to get it to play nicely. If that bundler doesn't work for you, there are others out there as well that you could try (Webpack and rollup are two popular ones). It should be possible though.

To actually provide assistance with exactly how to get it to work, we'd need to know a lot more, like your config and your code structure. In general though, make sure you're using relative paths within your code.

---

In general, bundling is a good idea. There are some exceptions to this though.

If you have discreet areas of the site accessed by different people (e.g., general user vs. admin), you may want to bundle that into two (or three, if they share common code which can be a common file) files instead of two.

Another exception is if the file is super-crazy huge, breaking it up may be better (but this is an extreme case).

Finally, another reason you would not want to bundle is if you are using HTTP/2. With HTTP/1, in general, you bundle because it's faster to send one big file then a number of smaller files because of HTTP/1's handshake. With HTTP/2, that formula changes as you can basically send multiple files with 1 handshake, in parallel, so sending numerous smaller files actually becomes faster.

For HTTP/2, it also depends on the users to support this with this browser. Support for it is coming along, and within the next year, should definitely be done. Right now, it's a bit of a gray area, and you'd ideally want to have personalized analytics to help guide your decision.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do what you are trying to do. There's nothing there that's forbidden, or out of bounds relative to what RequireJS supports.

You are asking `r.js` to trace the dependencies of `require` calls that are nested inside `require` calls. For this, you need to have `findNestedDependencies: true` in your build configuration. Otherwise `r.js` will only look at top-level `define` and `require` calls and process only those. There's a cost to processing nested dependencies so it is off by default.

Either that, or flatten your hierarchy of `require` calls. There *are* some cases where external constraints force you to have a hierarchy. However, a lot of times it is simply not needed.

ETA: I saw your edit. Your module is not a proper AMD module. It does call `define` but there's code outside the factory function you pass to `define`, which is a no-no.

When you create a bundle with `r.js` the code outside `define` is, by default, plopped as-is into the bundle. And this is problematic for your code. The `App` global is created only after `application.js` has obtained the modules required by the first `require`, but since `application.js` is part of the same bundle that contains `utilloader.js`, then this means that the code outside `utilloader.js`' `define` call has already tried running and failed because `App` is not defined yet. (There's a `wrapShim` option that would wrap code that executes in the global space in a `define` call, but it would not help you because you are using `define` already. And it can cause other problems.)

You should be able to get the behavior you want if you set your `r.js` configuration to produce a bundle for everything except `utilloader.js` and put `utilloader.js` in a second bundle. This way, the code for `utilloader.js` would not execute until it is requested. (Which is also what happens when you do not use the optimizer.) You'd have to do this for all modules that depend on `App` being defined. And there may be other constraints you have to take care of that are not evident in the portion of code that you show in your question. So something like:

```
({
    appDir: ".",
    baseUrl: "myapp",
    dir: "../scripts-build",
    mainConfigFile: 'myapp/application.js',
    modules: [
        {
            name: "application",
            exclude: ["modules/util/utilloader"],
        },
        {
            name: "modules/util/utilloader",
        }
    ],
})
```

You may want to try with `excludeShallow` too. Again, what would work specifically depends on details that are not in the question. You have to experiment.

**Ultimately, though, it would be better to have well-behaved AMD modules and stop relying on passing information through globals.**

---

Also note that unless you are using old versions of Underscore, Backbone and Marionette, they don't need a `shim` configuration, because they all call `define`. And you must not use `shim` for scripts that call `define`. At best, your `shim` for them has no effect. At worst it could have unintended effects. RequireJS does not specify semantics for using `shim` with files that call `define`. When I tried it in old versions, I got crashes. Newer versions appear to gracefully ignore `shim` in such cases, but you never know when problems may reoccur.

Comment: Thx for the response.  Well I removed the shim.  And I added findNestedDependencies: true to my build configuration.  No success yet but looks like that shook some things up.  I now get an undefined error.  See that variable "App" I set up in application.js.  It is defined in that file and no errors reported there.  But it is reported as undefined in utilloader.js, the first module that application.js tries to require.  Something about the hierarchy here is not agreeable.

Comment: Just looking at the code in your question I'm not seeing what would cause the problem you describe in your comment. Are your modules proper AMD modules (calling `define`)?

Comment: Hmmm.. I see a potential issue there. I'm using this prescription (https://johndavidmathis.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/structuring-scalable-client-side-applications/) for structuring my app. It may be in conflict with proper AMD define.  Specifically the feature in there "Permit modules to utilize multiple files and a logical folder structure" has me putting things outside the define in my modules.  I've posted the utilloader module above as an example. This runs fine non-optimized. No scope issues. I'm guessing the optimizer isn't fond of this - the mod def outside define to load multiple files?

Comment: @Robert Yeah, that's a problem. I've edited my answer to address the new information.

Comment: OK.  It's a large project - 100+ js files.  I've been working my way through them this afternoon trying to edit to fit the spec.  Basically I have to do the dependencies inline (not above define) and edit 90+ files that currently are not wrapped in define.  Quite a bit of work.  Not sure why it all runs fine without the optimizer.  If this is a no no I would think the non-optimized version would break in the exact same way.  Thought they'd be equivalent.  Guess optimizer more strict?  Anyway will continue Monday and post my result when I get through all the files.

Comment: No dice.  I posted an update above with details.  Basically the optimizer is not liking this notion of modules being defined across multiple files.  The things I define in the external files aren't usable (scoped) to the module.  If I make a model definition in one of them and include the file in the module dependency list the model definition isn't recognized in the module.